# How to run code that reads from stdin inside of Atom?

Tags: rust, stdin, text-editor, atom-editor

I'm looking for an `IDE-like` editor for Rust and I found that Atom now has the best support for it. I want to be able to run some code that reads from the standard input stream but I cannot enter any input. Here is the example code:

```
use std::io;
fn main() {
    println!("Write something");
    let mut guess = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
        .ok()
        .expect("Cannot read a string");

    println!("Your input is: {}", guess);
}
```

When I build it, it prints:

```
Executing: cargo  run
     Running `target\debug\guess_app.exe`
Write something

9.9s Building...
```

This falls into an infinite loop and does not allow me to enter any text. I can only stop running the code.

How can it be fixed? Maybe I can run it in `CMD` console, not sure...

I'm using the latest versions of `build`, `build-cargo`, `language-rust` and `racer`. I get this behaviour for the `Cargo.Run` command. I also tried a `script` package, but strange encoding problems occur in the output when I run it.

Comment: The build-package was never meant to interact with stdin. You probably need one of the terminal packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Terminal-plus](https://atom.io/packages/terminal-plus) package fit my needs, thanks for advice @ker